# Intercept outgoing calls on hangup

Tags: android

We want to intercept the outgoing call hangup state in a broadcast receiver. We are listening to `android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE` and do get notified on `IDLE` state, that is when the call finishes.

Unfortunately, we do not get the called number from the call log content provider. It always returns the last call. Interestingly the incoming call do send a number in the intent but nothing for outgoing call.

If we use `android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`, the phone number is coming through  the intent when the call starts, but this stage is too early for us to do any processing as we want to wait for the call to complete.

```
public class InterceptOutgoingCall extends BroadcastReceiver {
Boolean isOutGoingCall = true;
private static final String LOG_TAG = "InterceptOutgoingCall";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    //1. Logging the intent params

    String state = null;
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    if (intent.getAction() != null)
        buf.append("Intent action: " + intent.getAction());
    if (intent.getCategories() != null) {
        Set<String> categories = intent.getCategories();
        if (categories != null) {
            Iterator<String> it = categories.iterator();
            buf.append("; categories: ");
            int ctr = 0;
            for (; it.hasNext();) {
                String category = (String) it.next();
                if (ctr != 0)
                    buf.append("/");
                buf.append(category);
                ++ctr;
            }
        }
    }
    if (intent.getData() != null) {
        buf.append("; intent data: " + intent.getData().toString());
    }
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        buf.append("; extras: ");
        int ctr = 0;

        Set keys = extras.keySet();
        for (Iterator it = keys.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            String key = (String) it.next();
            Object value = extras.get(key);
            if (ctr != 0)
                buf.append("/");
            String strvalue = value == null ? "null" : value.toString();
            if (key.equals("state"))
                state = strvalue;
            buf.append(key + "=" + strvalue);
            ++ctr;
        }
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, buf.toString());
        if ("IDLE".equals(state)) {
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Number of the other party: "
                    + getLastCallLogEntry(context));
        }
    }

        String outgoingCall = CallLog.Calls.getLastOutgoingCall(context);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Last call:" + outgoingCall);


}

private String getLastCallLogEntry(Context context) {
    String[] projection = new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
            CallLog.Calls.NUMBER, CallLog.Calls.TYPE };
    ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cur = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, projection,
            null, null, CallLog.Calls.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);
    int numberColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int typeColumn = cur.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    if (!cur.moveToNext()) {
        cur.close();
        return "";
    }
    String number = cur.getString(numberColumn);
    String type = cur.getString(typeColumn);
    String dir = null;
    try {
        int dircode = Integer.parseInt(type);
        switch (dircode) {
        case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
            dir = "OUTGOING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
            dir = "INCOMING";
            break;

        case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
            dir = "MISSED";
            break;
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
    }
    if (dir == null)
        dir = "Unknown, code: " + type;
    cur.close();
    return dir + "," + number;
}
```

**Log cat**

*When call starts, NEW_OUTGOING_CALL is broadcast*

```
04-27 13:07:16.756: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): Intent action: android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL; extras: android.phone.extra.ALREADY_CALLED=false/android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER=999222/android.phone.extra.ORIGINAL_URI=tel:999-222
```

*Result data*

```
04-27 13:07:16.876: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): Result Data:999222
```

*Call Logs last call*

```
04-27 13:07:17.156: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): Last call:809090
```

*Next, PHONE_STATE is broadcast, No number in extras*

```
04-27 13:07:19.495: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): Intent action: android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE; extras: state=OFFHOOK
```

*No Result Data*

```
04-27 13:07:19.636: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): No result data
```

*When call is complete, No number in extras*

```
04-27 13:08:09.306: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): Intent action: android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE; extras: state=IDLE
```

*Call log last entry is the previously called number*

```
04-27 13:08:09.627: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): Number of the other party: OUTGOING,809090
04-27 13:08:09.675: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): No result data
04-27 13:08:10.336: INFO/InterceptOutgoingCall(775): Last call:809090
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a broadcast listener with an intent android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL string parametrer for the IntentFilter and don't forget to give permission in AndroidMenifest to PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS. This will work.

```
public static final String outgoing = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" ;
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(outgoing);
BroadcastReceiver OutGoingCallReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String outgoingno = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
        Toast.makeText(context, "outgoingnum =" + outgoingno,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};
registerReceiver(brForOutgoingCall, intentFilter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can the outgoing call number like below:

String number = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

I think you can store the number using public static variable and then refer it.